# Redirect directory to a file with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How, with .htaccess, I can redirect

```
domain.com/admin
```

to

```
domain.com/admin/index
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: By implementing a redirection rule. I suggest you take a look at 1. the documenttion of the tool you want to use and 2. the endless examples for what you are looking for which you can easily find here.

Comment: An alternative to a redirection (or internal rewrite) would be the `DocumentIndex` directive. Again: take a look into the documentation for that.